# Accessing JSON array elements in java

Tags: java, json

I have a json file and have used simple.json jar to parse the elements. I could parse the elements successfully. But what I want is that if my json file has three elements by same name, then I want to print each name only when their index is called.
get() prints out all the elements of that name.

Please help!

Following is the json file:

```
{
    "nodes":
    [
    {
        "node":"1",
        "ipaddr":"127.0.0.1",
        "port":"8443",
        "mgport":"9000"

    },
    {
        "node":"2",
        "ipaddr":"127.0.0.1",
        "port":"8556",
        "mgport":"9000"
    },
    {
        "node":"3",
        "ipaddr":"127.0.0.1",
        "port":"8000",
        "mgport":"9000"
    }

    ]
}
```

I need to retrive only one port value rather than all the values.

Comment: You should include the relevant section your code indicating what you have tried and where it's going wrong (including the relevant part of the JSON).

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used the JSON Processing library to do something similar to what you describe.

Here is the link for you to have a look: https://jsonp.java.net/

Could you post also an example of the JSON you'll like to parse?

Comment: You can use this library with any kind of parser you like. I have used it with Jackson and it worked brilliantly.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jackson for parsing JSON. It will make your life easier. 
This will help you.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson/jackson_first_application.htm

Thanks